# Matlab: Creating flat structure from Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a CELL array A in format:

```
  Month      Var1    Var2       Type 
  Q1-14      2.60   -1.50E+04    I 
  Q1-15      1.50   -2.20E+04    II 
  Q1-14      1.40   -2.50E+05    I 
  Q1-15      8.50   -2.90E+05    II
```

And I want to create the following format:

```
  Month      Type    Des     Value 
  Q1-14      I       Var1    2.60 
  Q1-15      II      Var1    1.50 
  Q1-14      I       Var1    1.40 
  Q1-15      II      Var1    8.50 
  Q1-14      I       Var2   -1.50E+04
  Q1-15      II      Var2   -2.20E+04
  Q1-14      I       Var2   -2.50E+05
  Q1-15      II      Var2   -2.90E+05
```

I must do this in Matlab. I can run a for loop to achieve this but I want something cleaner.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaner?"

Comment: Better way of doing it other than running a for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  Faster?  Uses less code?  Waits for the Walk signal before crossing the street?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not an elegant solution after all, but given the structure of your desired answer, this is what I could think of:

```
sz=size(A,1);
newA(:,1)=[A(:,1);A(2:end,1)];
newA(:,2)=[A(:,4);A(2:end,4)]
newA(:,3)=['Des';repmat(A(1,2),sz-1,1);repmat(A(1,3),sz-1,1)];
newA(:,4)=['Value';A(2:end,2);A(2:end,3)];
```

Comment: I don't think the above code keeps the Month and Type column together. But I will post the corrected code when I debug it.

Comment: for me it does. I get a 9x4 cell, thats what you want, right?

Comment: No you are right it does work. I might have fudged something. Thanks.

Comment: I have to remove the accept from this answer as this is not scalable. I still end up using a for loop with your code.

Comment: @user1243255 why this is not scalable? The `sz` variable makes it scalable. What is the exact problem?

Comment: I might consider as an acceptable answer as I have about 50 columns and rows 4 and 5 of your code need for loop to make it work but it is a trivial change I suppose. Thanks Parag.